# how print the function by the location in the list?

Tags: list, dictionary

data = [
{
'name': 'Instagram',
'follower_count': 346,
'description': 'Social media platform',
'country': 'United States'
},
{
'name': 'Cristiano Ronaldo',
'follower_count': 215,
'description': 'Footballer',
'country': 'Portugal'
},
{
'name': 'Ariana Grande',
'follower_count': 183,
'description': 'Musician and actress',
'country': 'United States'
}]

def dictionary_value():
for value in data:
return value["name"], value["follower_count"],value["description"], value["country"]

Hi, I'm newbie in python and i have a question about dictionary and lists:
i would like that my function dictionary value() will return only the values and print the function by the location in the list, for example: if i want to choose data[2] the outcome should be: 'Ariana Grande', 183,'Musician and actress','United States'. i could not find a way to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `dict.values` method:

```
def dictionary_value(i):
    return list(data[i].values())
```

Output:

```
print(dictionary_value(2))
# 'Ariana Grande', 183,'Musician and actress','United States'
```